# How to pass a dynamic 2 Dimensional to a function in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, function, multidimensional-array

This is a valid code according to c99 standard and this code-snippet is running fine on gcc compiler.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void foo( int n, int m, int a[][m]){
    //do stuff
}

int main() {
        int n,
            m;
        scanf("%d %d", &n, &m);
        int a[n][m];
        foo(n, m, a);
        return 0;
}
```

But the equivalent C++ code is not running on g++ compiler.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void foo( int n, int m, int a[][m]){
         //do stuff
}

int main() {
       int n,
           m;
    cin >> n >> m;
    int a[n][m];
    foo(n, m, a);
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting the following error.

```
error: use of parameter outside function body before ‘]’ token
void foo( int n, int m, int a[][m]){
```

I cannot find the simple solution in C++ as it available in C for this problem.

Comment: Which C++ standard are you compiling with? More importantly, does this program HAVE to be written in C++?

Comment: Any reason you expect two different languages have the same features?

Comment: if you use C++, why not using vectors? you won't believe how many users here have problems with C multi-dimensional arrays.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: That's nonsense. VLAs work fine in C. Just use a modern, compliant compiler.

Comment: @MasonWatmough C++11.
I am a C programmer and learning C++ that's why i tend to write program in   
C++, in order to learn C++.

Comment: The error you get seems very clear. Your C++ compiler warns you that you try to do something that can not be compiled, I mean using a parameter to define another parameter... I suggest you to replace the 2nd 'm' with a constant value, or simply remove it.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre so there is no solution available in C++ for this problem.

Comment: @abhishekjaiswal if you're trying to learn C++, check out [vectors](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/).

Comment: @abhishekjaiswal you might want to look at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/variable-length-arrays-in-c

Comment: @LaurentH. I tried to replace 2nd m with constant parameter but problem persist.

Comment: @abhishekjaiswal C++ is *not* C-with-classes, it's a different language, and the backwards compatibility only goes so far - variable length arrays, the thing you are trying to use, is one of the things that C++ does not include support for. If you want to actually learn C++, I encourage you to learn C++ rather than learning how to write C that the G++ compiler will accept.

Comment: @Olaf I think it is because of the unfortunate naming of the language, C++. It could be... D, nobody expects D to be source compatible with C. Furthermore, the ++ there kinda indicates C++ should be enhanced/improved C, so it's kinda counter-intuitive it's missing features of C (which is fine of course in itself, since it's a different language, not a version of C).

Comment: @hyde: Strange. While it sometimes happens, most don't think C# is the same as C. And no, it is not that VLAs are a "missing feature", it just does not have this feature (which is _one_ reason to stick with C in my projects).  And it is not just that both have different features, but they have different semantics for identical syntax&grammar, too. Just consider the `const` qualifier, then operator overloading (which is a questionable feature anyway). FYI: read the history, C++ started as a C preprocessor, so the similarity was well justified **that time**.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you must replace `m` in `int a[][m]` with some constant value, as you cannot use variables to define columns of arrays in function headers.

Second of all, you cannot declare arrays with variable size as you've done `int a[n][m]`, you have to use constants here too.

But if you want to use variable size arrays, you can create the arrays dynamically.

```
int** a = new int*[n]; // It creates an array of pointers of size n
```

and then you can loop through this array of pointers to allocate an array of integers to each of the pointer.

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    a[i] = new int[m];
}
```

this will create you a 2D array of integers dynamically.
And to pass this array as argument to some function, you can use pointer to pointer.

```
void foo(int n, int m, int** a){
     // here use it just like you use an array.
}
```

And when you are done using the array, you have to de-allocate the dynamically allocated array.

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    delete[] a[i];
    a[i] = 0;
}
delete[] a;
a = 0;
```

And if you don't like this method, you can always use [vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) class.

```
vector<vector<int>> a(n, vector<int>(m));
```

To pass a `vector` to a function.

```
void foo(const vector<vector<int>>& a){
    size_t n = a.size();
    size_t m = 0;
    if (n > 0)
        m = a[0].size();
    // do your work
}
```

When using `vector`, you don't have to worry about dynamic allocation or de-allocation, the `vector` class handles this kind of stuff itself.

Comment: In the vector of vectors example, `vector<vector<int>> a(n, vector<int>(m));` No loop is required. And regarding final example, since VLA's, like regular arrays in C, are passed by first-element-address as their value, the logical synonymous action for passing the vector of vectors to `foo` would be by *reference*. As-written, it is by-value.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

A simple solution in C++ for this problem would be to use a 2D vector

`vector <vector<int> > vecArray( 10, vector <int> (10) )`

and pass it to the function  by reference `&vec2DArray`.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;


//  function to pass 2d vector array by reference &
void function( int n, int m,  vector <vector<int> > & vec2DArray ) {

    for (int y=0; y<10; y++ ){
        for (int x=0; x<10; x++  ){

            // perform some calculations
            vec2DArray[y][x] = (y+1) * (x+1) *m *n;

        }
    }
}


int main() {
    cout<<"function to pass 2d vector array by reference & \n\n";

    // create a 2D vector of dimension [10][10]
    vector <vector<int> > vec2DArray( 10, vector <int> (10) );
    int n=0, int m=0;

    // call function, pass 2d vector array  by reference &
    function( 1, 1, vec2DArray );

    // display calculation results
    for (int y=0; y<10; y++ ){
        for (int x=0; x<10; x++  ){

            // display vec2DArray
            cout << setfill(' ') << setw(2)<< vec2DArray[y][x] <<" ";
        }  
        cout<<"\n";
    }
    cout<<"\n";


cout<<"Press ANY key to close.\n\n";
cin.ignore(); cin.get();
return 0;
}
```